# Import activity in Email Studio will fail when imported data has 0 records?

Tags: marketing-cloud, import, email-studio

Basically I want to keep my Data Extension up-to-date. So I created an import activity in Email Studio.

[image: Import activity in Email Studio]

Source is a report in Salesforce and Update type is **Overwrite** because I want my DE (the Data Extension is automatically created) has to be new based on the report. The report will be changed every day due to its filters. I noticed when my report had 0 records then it would still keep old records from previous import and did nothing.

This is bad in my case since I'm going to use an automation to update that DE daily and it should show correctly based on the current report. How can I solve this issue?

P/s: They didn't even mention about "Update type: **Overwrite** " in their document. Weird

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_an_import_activity.htm&type=5

Comment: FWIW, it's been a while since I used one of these, but I seem to remember SFMC uses FTP imports for these interactions behind the scenes. Have you asked for Support to "Enable the 'Allow Blank File Processing' Business Rule with quality of 'continue'". By default, FTP imports fail when the file's got no rows to import. It could be you're experiencing a silent error due to this.

Comment: @Macca Honestly I'm not sure how I should ask them. Do you think it's a bug or they intended to do that to avoid a conflict scenario? Have you ever done that before?

Comment: Hey. I'd just create a support case in the help portal and say: Hi, Please could you enable the 'Allow Blank File Processing' Business Rule with quality of 'continue'. Support like these types of cases because they're quick to do and ups their KPIs. I suspect you'd need to be a designated support contact to make this type of request these days, but if you already are the contact for your account, they'll enable the rule quickly.